# Deadlock Conditions (Coffman conditions)

Tags: c, operating-system, deadlock

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions][1]

in this wikipedia article, authors mentioned that in order for a deadlock to occur, four conditions must be true, (mutual exclusion, hold and wait, circular wait, no preemption). and if one is not verified there is no deadlock.

let's look at this situation.

```
semaphore s(0); // initialized with 0

wait(s);
rest of code...
```

as we can see the process is not going to make any progress, thus the definition of a deadlock is valid. while there is no other process can signal s, so no preemption is verified. but neither circular wait nor h&w nor mutex are. does a deadlock appear in this situation, and does all the conditions are verified ? or am i wrong about the definition of deadlocks?

Comment: i argued with my teacher about the necessity of the validity of the four conditions. so he came up with this example.

Comment: If consider the definition from the Wikipedia, `In concurrent computing, a deadlock is a state in which each member of a group is waiting for another member`. In your example there is no `another member`, hence it's not a deadlock-in-concurrent-computing

Comment: This is not deadlock. The program waits and makes no progress because it waits for an event/resource that no process will signal/release, not because of deadlock.

Comment: so this process isn't in a deadlock situation?

Comment: Eric posted 'This is not deadlock'.  Please explain how that is not clear.

Comment: This is logical bug like `while (1);` - it hangs program, but it is not deadlock.

Comment: @VillageTech thank you thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadlock happen when one process p1 and second process p2 competing for critical section:

```
p1: wait(Q); wait(S); ...
p2: wait(S); wait(Q); ...
```

- hold and wait: if process needs two semaphores like Q and S to go to critical section. p1 aquire Q and p2 aquire S, avail and claim what is available.
- no premption: none of process can forcefully stop another process to claim either Q or S
- mutual exclusion: only one process is allowed at a time.
- circular: p1->p2->p1 means p1 waiting for p2 to aquire S, and p2 waiting for p1 to aquire  Q. so none of them will be ever successful to go to critical section.

Sometimes all 3 above conditions are met but still its no deadlock. so it depends on situation.